# Identifying a plain object in pure JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, types

I'm trying to write a node.js script and want to keep the dependencies on the minimum. I want to make sure that a given argument called `config` is a plain object, like this:

```
var config = {
  'key1': 'val1',
  'key2': 'val2',
  'key3': 'val3'
  /* ... */
}
```

Now the first thing that came to mind was something like this:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(config) !== '[object Object]') {
  /* ... */
}
```

Can anyone think of an example where this wouldn't hold? I thought it was better to add:

```
if (typeof config !== 'object' ||
  Object.prototype.toString.call(config) !== '[object Object]') {
  /* ... */
}
```

just to be sure! But I'm still not convinced it could be this easy. I need

- **Critical analysis:** is it unsafe, is it an overkill or is it plain wrong! Any reason not to use this.
- **A better way:** something that you would do *instead*.

Thank you very much for your time folks.

---

I had a look at jQuery source, and particularly at the function `jQuery.isPlainObject()` and it uses a slightly more complex approach. Where I am looking to establish if it's a plain object, jQuery is making sure it's not anything other than a plain object. Have a look here:

```
isPlainObject: function( obj ) {
    // Not plain objects:
    // - Any object or value whose internal [[Class]] property is not "[object Object]"
    // - DOM nodes
    // - window
    if ( jQuery.type( obj ) !== "object" || obj.nodeType || jQuery.isWindow( obj ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( obj.constructor &&
            !hasOwn.call( obj.constructor.prototype, "isPrototypeOf" ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    // If the function hasn't returned already, we're confident that
    // |obj| is a plain object, created by {} or constructed with new Object
    return true;
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell using `Object.prototype.toString.call(config) !== '[object Object]'` is the most foolproof way there is. I cannot think of any situation where it could fail. Adding `typeof` shouldn't be needed and makes your code a little more confusing imo.

Comment: I think for any good answers to come in, we'll need a definition of what makes a "plain object" versus one that isn't plain.

Comment: @m90 I think it is... Unfortunately I searched for *"plain object"* because jQuery calls it so. I could have searched for *"object literal"* but I didn't know it was called that. Still this is a little different from that question. I'm asking if there's a *better* way.

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman As long as there's no `Object.isObject`: No.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I thought it was something already well known. But in any case, I tried to give a rudimentary explanation at the beginning of question. I have no idea what the exact definition is. I've just seen it called a *plain object*.

Comment: @m90 if there was `Object.isObject` it should return true for everything from strings to functions. Everything in JS is an object... :D

Comment: strings are not objects in JS... neither are booleans or numbers.

Comment: @ZiaUrRehman Well we could argue about that, but I guess we won't. If you expect (almost) everything to be an object you can already use `typeof`, this is why my hypothetical `Object.isObject` would do a better job.

Comment: for literals, obj.constructor === Object, or if you are overly-concerned: obj.constructor === ({}).constructor always works, unless constructor was modified or deleted. the only snag is screening for null first.

Comment: That jQuery version looks like it'd fail for a "plain object" that has a truthy property called `nodeType`.